# Using RStudio DevTools, can you prevent the Environment Pane from hiding column values with ellipses (...)

Tags: html, css, r, rstudio, inspect-element

I'd like my data to at least extend horizontally to the edge of the environment pane, but it gets truncated even if there is plenty of room left in the pane. Columns of class "chr" appear to be restricted to showing only the first 4 entries (yellow arrows in the first picture), and columns of class "num" and "int" tend to show either 5 or 10 values (green arrow in the first picture).

[image: ellipses hiding data]

Right-clicking on one of the rows and selecting "Inspect element" brings up RStudio DevTools; using that, I can at least enable a scroll bar by changing "overflow-x" from 'hidden' to 'scroll'. However, the scroll bar only scrolls to the original 4, 5, or 10 values that were shown, and then you still see the ellipsis. Changing "text-overflow" from 'ellipsis' to any of the other options seems to have no effect, nor does changing any of the other properties (padding-left/right, border, white-space).

[image: scroll bar]

I'd just like to see more data in that pane or enable a scroll bar at the bottom of the pane instead of for each individual row, but I can't find any settings to change to enable this. The theme I'm using is Tomorrow Night Bright if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely can't do it using RStudio DevTools.  RStudio implements their display using Chrome, so RStudio DevTools is just Chrome DevTools:  the truncation of values has already happened before Chrome sees it.

There's probably a variable somewhere in the RStudio sources that controls how the truncation takes place, but I don't know where.  You can look through the sources here if you want:  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio .  I kind of doubt that it will be something you can control from R, but you never know.

So I can't offer a general solution, but I can offer a small hack.  Normally I use this when I want to look at an expression:  many debuggers let you watch expressions, but RStudio just shows you existing variables.  However, if you want to see `x+y` in the environment pane, you can just calculate it in the console:

```
`x+y` <- x+y
```

and it will be displayed.  (You've also created a new variable, and possibly stomped on an existing one.)  This doesn't change like a live expression, so it's not that great, but it's better than nothing.

For your purpose, the thing to calculate would be something to display the missing bits of your display.  If you want to see more `manufacturer` values, then do something like

```
mfr <- paste(mpg$manufacturer, collapse = " ")
```

This creates one long string, and will show as much of it as will fit.